# In Python, with a list of extracted values from file, how to find sum of column of float values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble find the sum of a column with a list of values that is extracted from a txt file using Python 3. The file contains data that looks something like:

- 1800    -0.19    -0.11
- 1801    -0.1     -0.17
- 1802    -0.2     -0.11
- .
- .       [cont.]
- .
- 1900    -0.15    -.15

How can I find the sum of the second and third columns separately?

First, I opened the file using

```
with open('file.txt') as f:

for line in f:
    column_2 = line.split()
    b = float(column_2[-2])

    print(b)
```

I was able to print the second column of values successfully. However, after I added:

```
print(sum(b))
```

It was not able to run the code.

When I run the code, I am given the error:

```
'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code.

Firstly, you have assigned some value to `sum`. **Do not use builtin names for your variables**.

Execute `del sum` and everything will be fine.

*However*, your logic is still wrong because doing that only takes the sum of the *last value of b*. You need to store all values you have seen somewhere.

With the way you are doing things, the best method would be using an accumulator variable:

```
b_sum = 0

for line in f:
    column_2_value = float(line.split()[-2])
    b_sum += column_2_value
```

A better approach, IMO, is to load the entire data structure into memory:

```
with open('Global_Temperature_Data_File.txt') as f:
    data = [row.split() for row in f.read().split('\n')]
    transposed_data = list(zip(*data))
```

This will turn `transposed_data` into a nested `list`, where each inner element represents one column.

You can then just do this:

```
b_sum = sum(transposed_data[2])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful response, I really appreciate it. I also tried your approach and it says that there is a syntax error in the line "transposed_data = list(zip(*data)" but the previous code worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @python_n00b I realised I forgot a `]` in the previous line, so I edited it. If you try it again, it should work!

Comment: I copy and pasted the edited code and it came back with the error 'list' object is not callable in same line of code with the previous error :/

Comment: @python_n00b I believe you have also assigned something to the variable `list`. You will need to execute `del list`. As a reminder: **don't assign stuff to builtin names**!

Answer (score 0):

How about reading the lines from the file and then using `split()` get your columns and with `sum()` you can compute the sum. Obviously, this will only work if your lines have the same structure.

```py
with open('Global_Temperature_Data_File.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


second_column_sum = sum([float(line.split('-')[1]) for line in lines])
third_column_sum = sum([float(line.split('-')[2]) for line in lines])
```

*Here I assumed your values are positive and `-` is a separator, if this is not the case, use `line.split(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

If you added your print statement inside the loop, this will not work as you're hoping. `sum` needs an iterable, like a list. `sum(b)` in your case will fail (though when I tried to replicate your error I got a slightly different one!).

I suggest you change your code to have `b=0' before your for loop, and the`b=...`line to be`b + = ...` . This will sum up the values as you go through the loop.

Note that you might have problems if some rows on your dataset are not numbers...